# Fire up event every few milliseconds without using a timer

Tags: c#, winforms

My application takes a Wireshark file and plays the packets. From the main thread I am checking my class which plays the packets and update my gui and I want to fire up my update event every 200 milliseconds instead of all the time without using timer (winform application)

```
        listBoxFiles.SetSelected(0, true);
        bgWoSingle = new BackgroundWorker();
        bgWoSingle.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bgWoSingle.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bgW_ProgressChanged);
        bgWoSingle.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(
        (s3, e3) =>
        {
            while (loopsCount < numberOfLoops && bContinuePlay && ifContinue)
            {
                for (int i = 0; (i < listBoxFiles.Items.Count) && bContinuePlay && ifContinue; i++)
                {
                    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                    {
                        lbCurrentFileNum.Text = "(" + (i + 1) + "/" + listBoxFiles.Items.Count + "):";
                    });

                    string path = (string)listBoxFiles.Items[i];
                    pcap = new Pcap(path, playSpeed, isSync);
                    pcap._startTimer += new EventHandler(pcap_packetStartTimer);
                    pcap._stopTimer += new EventHandler(pcap__packetStopTimer);
                    //this is the event i want to fire every 200 milliseconds
                    *********************************************************
                    pcap.evePacketProgress += new Pcap.dlgPacketProgress(
                        (progressCount) =>
                        {
                            pcap._fileSelectedIndex = i;
                            bgWoSingle.ReportProgress(progressCount, pcap);
                        });
                   *********************************************************

                    if (selectedAdapter != null)
                    {
                        bContinuePlay = pcap.playCapture(selectedAdapter._packetDevice);
                    }
                }

                loopsCount++;
            }

        });

        bgWoSingle.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(
            (s3, e3) =>
            {

            }
            );

        bgWoSingle.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use a timer? That's what they are for.

Comment: Maybe use `Thread.Sleep` in your loop?

Comment: i prefer to avoid Thread.Sleep becuse i want the option to kill the prosecc in the middle with Stop button, is it more simple with timer ?

Comment: @user979033 I gave you the code earlier, it stores the last time event fired and only fires if 200 ms has passed. you got some problem in it?

Comment: the code include some of characters that i cannot read

Comment: Please explain why you want to avoid timers. How should we recommend good alternate solutions, if we don't know why you rejected the obvious solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a array of DateTime instances.

```
var lastTimes = new DateTime[listBoxFiles.Items.Count];
```

and use them as below.

```
 pcap.evePacketProgress += new Pcap.dlgPacketProgress((progressCount) =>
                    {
                        pcap._fileSelectedIndex = i;
                        if(lastTimes[i] !=null && DateTime.Now-lastTimes[i] <= new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0,200))
                             return;
                        lastTimes[i]  = DateTime.Now;
                        bgWoSingle.ReportProgress(progressCount, pcap);
                    });
```

Comment: Index was out of range, must be non negative

Answer (score 0):

You can do a game loop and check the elapsed time using a `Stopwatch` object. I have a form with a check box (event active or not), and a text box for visual validation that it works. For every tick I add a `|` to the text box.

```
public partial class RunningForm : Form
{
    #region Windows API - User32.dll
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct WinMessage
    {
        public IntPtr hWnd;
        public Message msg;
        public IntPtr wParam;
        public IntPtr lParam;
        public uint time;
        public System.Drawing.Point p;
    }

    [System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity] // We won't use this maliciously
    [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern bool PeekMessage(out WinMessage msg, IntPtr hWnd, uint messageFilterMin, uint messageFilterMax, uint flags);

    [System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity] // We won't use this maliciously
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendNotifyMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    #endregion

    Stopwatch sw;
    public event EventHandler RepeatTick;

    public RunningForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.sw=new Stopwatch();
    }

    public void UpdateForm()
    {
        // Check if 200ms have passed
        if(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds>=200 )
        {
            if(this.RepeatTick!=null)
            {
                this.RepeatTick(this, System.EventArgs.Empty);
            }
            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();
        }
    }

    #region Main Loop
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        sw.Start();
        // Hook the application's idle event
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.Idle+=new EventHandler(OnApplicationIdle);
        this.RepeatTick+=new EventHandler(RunningForm_RepeatTick);
    }

    void RunningForm_RepeatTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.AppendText("|");
    }

    private void OnApplicationIdle(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        while(AppStillIdle)
        {
            if(checkBox1.Checked)
            {
                UpdateForm();
            }
        }
    }

    private bool AppStillIdle
    {
        get
        {
            WinMessage msg;
            return !PeekMessage(out msg, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 0);
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

and the result:

[image: RunningForm Screenshot]